# Install ubuntu over other linux distro and keeping dual boot with windows

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, upgrade

I am a bit lost.

On my system I have installed windows, then Kali Linux (yes I know, bad idea). I want to swap out kali linux for ubuntu, but still keep windows as something I can boot into. Here's how my disks and partitions are setup: http://prnt.sc/cjfqty

I think I can just go in and install ubuntu ontop of kali linux - as well as delete kali's bootloader by partitioning that space, but is the bootloader going to work afterwards?)

Comment: Not sure how you are partitioned, Probably better to post `sudo parted -l`. Generelly you should be able to just use Something Else and choose existing Linux partition. But I am not seeing swap, and system looks like BIOS with 4 primary partition limit. You always install grub2's boot loader to a drive like sda, never to a partition like sda1.

Comment: @oldfred I got 2 ssds and 1 hdd. The hdd is storage, one ssd is windows and one kali. Any bootloaders were installed automatically

Comment: Use Something Else and be sure to choose existing / as new / with ext4 format and choose the Linux SSD as drive to install grub2's boot loader into. You want to keep a Windows boot loader in MBR of Windows SSD. Default install of grub is normally to sda, which usually overwrites the Windows boot loader which you do not want. After install set BIOS to boot Ubuntu drive. Only if issues with Windows then in BIOS you can directly boot Windows if Windows boot loader in its MBR.